# Anyone able to identify this mite?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, arachnology, arthropod

[image]Located in a chicken coop crawling on windows. I’m guessing this is a bird mite as I’m only seeing them at night on the coop itself, but want to confirm so that I’m able to treat them effectively. I was able to get this picture by using my microscope with the 10x lens. The size of a grain of salt. Located in Wisconsin. [image]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Please [edit] your post to include as much [information](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/species-identification/info) as possible to improve your chances of getting a good answer: 1) closeup photos of the organism from multiple angles if possible; 2) how you acquired this image (it looks like you may have used a dissecting scope?) and what magnification you are using; and 3) an estimate of the size of the organism. ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site.

Comment: to get rid of bird mites you can use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diatomaceous_earth i have used it myself in our chicken coop and it is effective against mites.if you take a look at the ceiling where your chickens rest at night you will find a lot more mites.

Comment: Thanks! Just dusted with DE tonight. I bought elector PSP so I wouldn’t have to mess around, but here I am messing around. Sprayed yesterday for the second time. They are relentless.

Comment: Your Answer : (CM/Red Mite) https://entomology.ca.uky.edu/ef516

Comment: Sorry, without actual access to the mite, identification is practically impossible - there's just too many different species it could be to actually choose one. As for control, clean the coop regularly and dust with diatomaceous earth to kill any remaining mites.